# How to extract the image path?

Tags: java, swt, jface

```
Image img = new Image(null, path);
new Label(composite, SWT.LEFT).setImage(img);
```

This is my code and I want to fetch the image path from same package, because I want to export this project to a jar file.

**How to extract the image path?** (I'm not using plugin project) It's a SWT project.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You want to get the path relative to the class you are in?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileInputStream` or `getResourceAsStream`.

See here 
[Using FileInputStream](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/LoadimagefromfileCreateaninputstreamandpasstheinputstreamtotheconstructor.htm) and 
[Using getResourceAsStream](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/LoadimagefromfileaninputstreamandClassgetResourceAsStream.htm)